# shiny with rCharts: column stacking behavior

Tags: r, highcharts, shiny, rcharts

I'm relatively new to shiny and rCharts.
I tried to make an app with a stacked highcharts plot.

Usually if I exclude one variable in the legend, the plot adjusts automatically (y-axis, bars reorganise).
This does not work in my app.

Here you can find code to reproduce this minimal example:

```r
library(shiny)
library(rCharts)
runApp(list(
  ui = navbarPage("strange stack behavior",
                  tabPanel("highcharts column",
                           pageWithSidebar(
                             headerPanel("stacking"),

                             sidebarPanel(radioButtons("plotType", "Plot type", c("stacked"="percent", "barplot"="")
                             ),
                             width = 2
                             ),                              
                             mainPanel(showOutput("stackchart", "Highcharts"))
                           ))),
  server = (function(input, output) {

      data <- matrix(c(300, 200, 1400, 350, 50, 300, 1350, 700, 3000), nrow=3, byrow = T)
      dimnames(data) <- list(c("xA", "xB", "xC"), c("catA", "catB", "catC"))
      data <- as.data.frame(data)

    output$stackchart <- renderChart2({
      # Create chart
      a <- rCharts:::Highcharts$new()
      a$chart(type = "column")
      a$title(text = "charttitle")
      a$xAxis(categories = rownames(data))
      a$yAxis(title = list(text = "yaxis"))
      a$data(data)
      a$exporting(enabled=T)

      # credits with hyperlink
      a$credits(text = "somethingsomthing", href = "")
      # stacked
      a$plotOptions(
        column = list(stacking = input$plotType)
      )

      # title & subtitle
      a$title(text = "title")
      a$subtitle(text = "subtitle")
      return(a)
    })
  })
))
```

Thanx for any input how to understand whats going on there!!
Best
Tobias

Comment: Your example works perfectly fine to me -- bars and y-axis reorganize as I click on the column names, either I start it from R Studio pop-up window, or from the bare R console using Safari or Chrome (everything was tried under Mac OS)...

Comment: Well, thanx for your reply! I'm working on a windows machine...might this be the reason...? It's still not working...(there was a little mistake in the code. I edited it just now.                                                                 > Sys.info()
"Windows"        "7 x64"   "build 9200"      "x86-64"

Comment: Make sure that you use the latest version of rCharts. If the problem persists, check if it is reproduced in different web browsers.

Comment: hell yes!!  `require(devtools); install_github('rCharts', 'ramnathv')` 
... problem solved...i had an old version of rCharts... . Thank you so much!!